# How to know if all elements in a DIV have been fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, load

There is a `div` in which there will be some elements (images, iframe, etc) being loaded via Ajax. After those elements have been fully loaded, I need to execute a function for the `div`.

How do I determine if all elements in the `div` have been fully loaded?

I use jQuery as the library.

Comment: For images and iframes, you can use `load` event...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For images and iframes you can use `load` event:

```
// get all images and iframes
var $elems = $('#div').find('img, iframe');

// count them
var elemsCount = $elems.length;

// the loaded elements flag
var loadedCount = 0;

// attach the load event to elements
$elems.on('load', function () {
    // increase the loaded count 
    loadedCount++;

    // if loaded count flag is equal to elements count
    if (loadedCount == elemsCount) {
        // do what you want
        alert('elements loaded successfully');
    }
});
```

*You should execute the above script after appending your elements via Ajax into your `#div` element.*

Comment: Not sure if I missed something, but the function doesn't seem to fire when the number of `img` and `iframe` is 0.

Comment: @IanY. Yes, you are correct, You should check for that: `if (elemsCount == 0) { alert('no element at all'); }`

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate your question. There are different methods for different type of elements.

For iframe follow this thread,
[How can I detect whether an iframe is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded)

For image
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

for flash it depends lots of things.
[How can I tell if Flash is loaded on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865555/how-can-i-tell-if-flash-is-loaded-on-a-website)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I don't need to care about flash. My OP has been updated.